# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `Name` on serializer `UserSerializer`

Tags: python, django, serialization

I got the following error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `Name` on
> serializer `UserSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
> incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'Name'.

Why do I get an error?

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Profile
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'Name', 'secondName', 'user', 'nickName', 'phoneNumber')
        """extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}"""

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
        print('Loogg')
        return user
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

"""Define Profile Fields"""
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    secondName = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    nickName = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    phoneNumber = models.IntegerField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'profiles'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import UserViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

Thanks,

I am quite new to Django so it could be a stupid error.

Comment: `queryset = Profile.objects.all()` instead of `queryset = User.objects.all()` ?

Comment: Thanks @ArakkalAbu that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

queryset = Profile.objects.all() instead of queryset = User.objects.all()

– Arakkal Abu